# How to echo information from xml in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have some problems with echo line from xml file. 
How i can do it fine?

I try to

```
$test = file_get_contents('');
$test = iconv('WINDOWS-1251', 'UTF-8', $test);
$test = "<xmp>".$test."</xmp>";
```

And try to find with preg_match_all, but it isn't work.

```
preg_match_all('/<ya:created dc:date="\d+\-\d+\-\d+\T\d+\:\d+\:\d+/', $test, $output_array);
```

It's work on https://www.phpliveregex.com/ but isn't work on my site.

```
https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/qCH
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1251"?>
<rdf:RDF
    xml:lang="ru"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
    xmlns:ya="http://blogs.yandex.ru/schema/foaf/"
    xmlns:img="http://blogs.yandex.ru/schema/foaf/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
  <foaf:Person>
    <ya:publicAccess>allowed</ya:publicAccess>
    <foaf:gender>male</foaf:gender>
    <ya:created dc:date="2011-01-30T16:43:45+03:00"/>
    <ya:lastLoggedIn dc:date="2019-01-16T18:54:55+03:00"/>
    <ya:modified dc:date="2019-01-13T21:15:43+03:00"/>
  </foaf:Person>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: What is your PHP version? Is it different to the version on phpliveregex.com?

Comment: Your question is _very_ unclear. Are you trying to get data from XML and print it? Then you should use SimpleXML instead of regex. Regex is not a good tool to parse XML-based markup. Btw, what's this suppose to return: `file_get_contents('');`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better accessing it using something like SimpleXML and XPath.  There are at least two ways of doing it, both here rely on using XPath but you have to use the namespaces (the `ya:` bit) to ensure you get the right element.  As XPath returns a list of matches, I just use `[0]` to get the first one, if there are multiple ones you can use a loop...

```
$test = file_get_contents("data.xml");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($test);

// Version 1
// Fetch the ya:created element
$created = $xml->xpath("//ya:created")[0];
// Extract the attributes and print the date
echo $created[0]->attributes("http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/")->date;

// Version 2
// Extract the dd:date attribute (using the @)
$createdDate = $xml->xpath("//ya:created/@dc:date")[0];
echo $createdDate;
```

Forgot to say - if you want to use these fields for a database etc. you may need to cast them to a string to make sure they are converted...

```
$date = (string)$createdDate;
```